# Path rewriting/aliasing upon SSH connection

Tags: ssh, rewrite

I've migrated my git repositories from Gitlab to Gogs and I've taken the opportunity to change some organization/group names and reorganize repositories.

I'd like to maintain the current Git+SSH URLs working however for projects using composer or other packagers.

I've looked for a way to do it inside Gogs but nothing seems to exist to this purpose so I had another idea (which could also be useful in other contexts): rewriting the SSH path on the server, like Apache does with mod_rewrite. Is there a way to do just that with SSH? Note that adding a command in the `.authorized_keys` is a bit tricky since Gogs already uses it to mediate access to the repositories through a command.

Comment: So you want to say that URL to your repo changed and you want to fix it for your repos but not submodules? If so you probably want something like this: `git config --global url.ssh://git@gogs.example.com/.insteadOf git@gitlab.com:`

Comment: @JiriB Not exactly, I have a repo, say "https://git.example.com/org1/repo1" whose URL is now "https://git.example.com/other_org_name/other_repo_name" and I'd like the old URL to keep working.

Comment: And I'd like it to work for any developer on the project without them having to do any config on their side, if possible.

Comment: Thus it must be server side. I don't know Gogs but I would check how `git` user on Gogs server works, ie. what command does it run when one does `git` over SSH. IIUC `git` over SSH is just calling `git` in the end with some args. If you see https://github.com/gogs/gogs/blob/main/internal/ssh/ssh.go then you can see that in *trace* log level you could see what was called from SSH client (a git user). Basically if Gogs doesn't have any feature for this, you could write a wrapper which would get "old" path from SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND and rewrite it and then call `git` as Gogs does by default.

Comment: Or maybe server-side `git` hooks could be used, I have no experience with that.

Comment: @JiriB Thank you for looking into this. Yes, this was my idea as well, wrapping a script around the command. The command that is called is something like "gogs serv key-1 ...". The problem is that this is the same gogs as the main process and "gogs serv" is also used in webhooks so it's not trivial to replace it by a custom script. Add replacing the command won't work since when a new user will import a new SSH key, my wrapper has to be put inside .authorize_keys...

Comment: I meant to write wrapper for server-side `git` command which is used.

Comment: That command is called inside th Go code, though, That would require patching the git library.

Comment: The command is `git` called from Go, so `git` would be your wrapper calling eg. `/usr/bin/git.orig`.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand your comment above at first. Thank you, I'll try something like hacking into SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much tweaking around, I concluded that there's nothing built into SSH to perform what mod_rewrite does for Apache2, most probably for excellent reasons.

So, I instead resorted to replacing the `gogs` command, called from SSH (in the `.authorized_keys` file by a script that rewrites the environment variable SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND and then calls the real gogs executable.

The SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND is the variable into which SSH writes the command sent to the server before calling the command written in `.authorized_keys` (when there is one). In the case of gogs, this variable is used to check that the repository exists, verify that it belongs to the SSH user logged in, etc. and finally perform the git operation on it. By changing the repository path in this variable, it's possible to alias repositories on-the-fly.